# How to get the path from the Dijkstra algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, dijkstra, adjacency-matrix

I took the code for the Dijkstra algorithm from [this website](https://www.scaler.com/topics/data-structures/dijkstra-algorithm/) and rewrote it for my needs (see below). Now I need to implement a feature that would store the shortest path for each node. I tried implementing it using [this code from Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-paths-dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm/) as guideline but failed miserably. Below is the code for my graph class:

```py
class Graph: 
    max_int = 999999
    def __init__(self, vertices, adj_matrix, start, target):
        # Get the vertices
        self.vertices = vertices

        self.start = start # an integer

        self.size = len(self.vertices)

        self.adj_matrix = adj_matrix # an adjacency matrix 

    def min_distance(self, distance, shortest_path_arr):
        min_distance = self.max_int

        for i in range(self.size):
            if distance[i] < min_distance and shortest_path_arr[i] == False:
                min_distance = distance[i]
                min_index = i
        
        return min_index
    
    def dijkstra(self):
        distance = [self.max_int] * self.size
        distance[self.start] = 0
        shortest_path_arr = [False] * self.size

        for vertex in range(self.size):
            x = self.min_distance(distance, shortest_path_arr)

            shortest_path_arr[x] = True

            for i in range(self.size):
                if self.adjMatrix[x][i] > 0 and shortest_path_arr[i] == False and distance[i] > distance[x] + self.adjMatrix[x][i]:
                    distance[i] = distance[x] + self.adjMatrix[x][i]
```

What should I do to get the path in the right order?

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that we can run ourselves along with this extra explanation.

Comment: When you visit a new node, you need to record the node you reached the new node from ( predecessor node ).  When you find a new, shorter path to a node you need to update the predecessor node.  Finally you can find the, reversed, route to any node by backtracking from the end node to the start node.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the distance from a list of ints to a list of pairs, in python that would be a tuple.
Another way is just to have another list which contains the previous node in the path for every node.
Then you add to this line:

```py
distance[i] = distance[x] + self.adjMatrix[x][i]
```

And set `parent[start]=start`, when 'start' is the node you start the search from.
something like `previous[i]=x`. 
Then, you can create a function that gets a node and the parents, and returns the path to it like this:

```py
def get_parents(parent, start, end):
    ans = [end]
    cur = end
    while (parent[cur] != cur):
        cur = parent[cur]
        ans.append(cur)
    return ans[::-1] #we reverse because we added the nodes from the end to the start
```